# Will Google Chrome Frame be Installable on Locked down Windows Machines?

Tags: windows, plugins, html, google-chrome

Does anyone know if [Google Chrome Frame](http://googlewavedev.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-wave-in-internet-explorer.html) will be installable onWindows machines in the dreaded Corporate IT World where machines are locked down with a Khaki Fist?

I suppose that's really two questions

1. Can Windows be locked down to prevent IE from installing plug-ins?
2. Is Google being clever and finding a way around this? (i.e., is the Google Chrome Frame install process somehow working around these restrictions)

(this is borderline Server Fault, but as it involves a programming run time and I'm interested in this from a programmers perspective, I ask here)

Comment: interested in this too. Unless it can be installed on PCs behind corporate firewalls I just cannot see the point of it at all.

Comment: Well, it gives corps the option.  They may have an "IE 6" only policy that can't bend, but a more flexible plug-in policy, and it looks like GCF features are off by default unless you include a special meta-tag on your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will very much depend on the network in question and how draconian (i.e. sensible) they are being with Internet Explorer.  IEs plugins have often been a source of major security flaws in the browser so a lot of networks do restrict the ability to install plugins.

When I worked in a large secondary school as an IT technician (equivalent to a High School) we had things locked down pretty tightly.  If we needed to install updated versions of Flash or similar we had to go round logging in as Administrators (thankfully we had remote management software to allow partial automation of this) to do it because ordinary users couldn't install plugins to IE.

I would think most corporate networks would restrict the ability to install plugins similarily.

With regards to part 2 of your question no Google are not since they can't, they're basically providing a plugin that basically lets the Chrome rendering and Javascript engine run inside IE.  This allows them to use standards compliant HTML5 which IE is very behind on implementing and has only as of a couple of weeks ago actually committed to implementing some of the key multimedia features of the specification which are needed for things like Google Wave and future web apps.
See http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/09/ie-program-manager-endorses-html-5-multimedia-tags.ars

Comment: +1 for good info, but I think you misunderstood #2 (have clarified).  I was asking if the Google Chrome Frame install process somehow worked around standard browser security setting.  Unlikely, but certainly possible.

Comment: No I don't think it can because it is a full blown plugin and I think it unlikely that Google of all people would attempt to circumvent security